# Checking fuzzy/approximate substring existing in a longer string, in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, fuzzy-search

Using algorithms like leveinstein ( leveinstein or difflib) , it is easy to find approximate matches.eg.

```
>>> import difflib
>>> difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,"amazing","amaging").ratio()
0.8571428571428571
```

The fuzzy matches can be detected by deciding a threshold as needed.

Current requirement : To find fuzzy substring based on a threshold in a bigger string.

eg.

```
large_string = "thelargemanhatanproject is a great project in themanhattincity"
query_string = "manhattan"
#result = "manhatan","manhattin" and their indexes in large_string
```

One brute force solution is to generate all substrings of length N-1 to N+1 ( or other matching length),where N is length of query_string, and use levenstein on them one by one and see the threshold.

Is there better solution available in python , preferably an included module in python 2.7 , or an externally available module .

**---------------------UPDATE AND SOLUTION ----------------**

Python regex module works pretty well, though it is little bit slower than inbuilt `re` module for fuzzy substring cases, which is an obvious outcome due to extra operations.
The desired output is good and the control over magnitude of fuzziness can be easily defined.

```
>>> import regex
>>> input = "Monalisa was painted by Leonrdo da Vinchi"
>>> regex.search(r'\b(leonardo){e<3}\s+(da)\s+(vinci){e<2}\b',input,flags=regex.IGNORECASE)
<regex.Match object; span=(23, 41), match=' Leonrdo da Vinchi', fuzzy_counts=(0, 2, 1)>
```

Comment: The `regex` solution does work for the given example. What problem are you having with it?

Comment: I would name the variable as `txt` or something else, instead of `input` which is a python keyword :).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The new regex library that's soon supposed to replace re includes fuzzy matching.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/

The fuzzy matching syntax looks fairly expressive, but this would give you a match with one or fewer insertions/additions/deletions.

```
import regex
regex.match('(amazing){e<=1}', 'amaging')
```

Comment: FWIW, the fuzzy matching sadly might be removed for the version intended to be added to the standard library... if it ever actually gets in, that is.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with the OP's "manhattan" example -- can you show the code to make that work?

Comment: It's a shame that `regex.match('(test){e<=1}', '123 test')` doesn't match anything

Comment: @AwaisHussain - did you try `regex.search('(test){e<=1}', '123 test')`? I wouldn't expect that match call to return a hit.

Comment: @EthanFurman did you try this? `for m in regex.findall('(manhattan){e<2}', "thelargemanhatanproject is a great project in themanhattincity"): print(m)`. This gives `manhatan` and `manhattin`.

Answer (score 23):

I use [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy) to fuzzy match based on threshold and [fuzzysearch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzysearch) to fuzzy extract words from the match.

`process.extractBests` takes a query, list of words and a cutoff score and returns a list of tuples of match and score above the cutoff score.

`find_near_matches` takes the result of `process.extractBests` and returns the start and end indices of words. I use the indices to build the words and use the built word to find the index in the large string. `max_l_dist` of `find_near_matches` is 'Levenshtein distance' which has to be adjusted to suit the needs.

```
from fuzzysearch import find_near_matches
from fuzzywuzzy import process

large_string = "thelargemanhatanproject is a great project in themanhattincity"
query_string = "manhattan"

def fuzzy_extract(qs, ls, threshold):
    '''fuzzy matches 'qs' in 'ls' and returns list of 
    tuples of (word,index)
    '''
    for word, _ in process.extractBests(qs, (ls,), score_cutoff=threshold):
        print('word {}'.format(word))
        for match in find_near_matches(qs, word, max_l_dist=1):
            match = word[match.start:match.end]
            print('match {}'.format(match))
            index = ls.find(match)
            yield (match, index)
```

To test:

```
query_string = "manhattan"
print('query: {}\nstring: {}'.format(query_string, large_string))
for match,index in fuzzy_extract(query_string, large_string, 70):
    print('match: {}\nindex: {}'.format(match, index))

query_string = "citi"
print('query: {}\nstring: {}'.format(query_string, large_string))
for match,index in fuzzy_extract(query_string, large_string, 30):
    print('match: {}\nindex: {}'.format(match, index))

query_string = "greet"
print('query: {}\nstring: {}'.format(query_string, large_string))
for match,index in fuzzy_extract(query_string, large_string, 30):
    print('match: {}\nindex: {}'.format(match, index))
```

Output:

```
query: manhattan  
string: thelargemanhatanproject is a great project in themanhattincity  
match: manhatan  
index: 8  
match: manhattin  
index: 49  

query: citi  
string: thelargemanhatanproject is a great project in themanhattincity  
match: city  
index: 58  

query: greet  
string: thelargemanhatanproject is a great project in themanhattincity  
match: great  
index: 29
```

Comment: index = ls.find(match) will only return the first occurrence.

Comment: Excellent, but currently falls foul of https://github.com/taleinat/fuzzysearch/issues/13 - so you need to add: `if len(ls) < len(qs): return; yield` (following https://stackoverflow.com/a/6266586/1021819).

Answer (score 23):

The approaches above are good, but I needed to find a small needle in lots of hay, and ended up approaching it like this:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher as SM
from nltk.util import ngrams
import codecs

needle = "this is the string we want to find"
hay    = "text text lots of text and more and more this string is the one we wanted to find and here is some more and even more still"

needle_length  = len(needle.split())
max_sim_val    = 0
max_sim_string = u""

for ngram in ngrams(hay.split(), needle_length + int(.2*needle_length)):
    hay_ngram = u" ".join(ngram)
    similarity = SM(None, hay_ngram, needle).ratio() 
    if similarity > max_sim_val:
        max_sim_val = similarity
        max_sim_string = hay_ngram

print max_sim_val, max_sim_string
```

Yields:

```
0.72972972973 this string is the one we wanted to find
```

Comment: How do we get the starting index of the substring?

Comment: Not bulletproof, but you could simply use the `find` string method

`index = hay.find(max_sim_string)`

Answer (score 21):

How about using `difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks`?

```
>>> import difflib
>>> large_string = "thelargemanhatanproject"
>>> query_string = "manhattan"
>>> s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, large_string, query_string)
>>> sum(n for i,j,n in s.get_matching_blocks()) / float(len(query_string))
0.8888888888888888

>>> query_string = "banana"
>>> s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, large_string, query_string)
>>> sum(n for i,j,n in s.get_matching_blocks()) / float(len(query_string))
0.6666666666666666
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
import difflib

def matches(large_string, query_string, threshold):
    words = large_string.split()
    for word in words:
        s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, word, query_string)
        match = ''.join(word[i:i+n] for i, j, n in s.get_matching_blocks() if n)
        if len(match) / float(len(query_string)) >= threshold:
            yield match

large_string = "thelargemanhatanproject is a great project in themanhattincity"
query_string = "manhattan"
print list(matches(large_string, query_string, 0.8))
```

Above code print: `['manhatan', 'manhattn']`

Comment: How to retrieve the fuzzily matched substring from the blocks ? eg "manhatan"

Comment: @DhruvPathak, `a = "thelargemanhatanproject"; b = "manhattan"; s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b); ''.join(a[i:i+n] for i, j, n in s.get_matching_blocks() if n)`

Comment: it does not extract "manhatan" from the large_string, it results in the query_string "manhattan" (double t)

Comment: @DhruvPathak, ?? The code in my comment yield `'manhatan'`. (single t)

Comment: Can your code be extended to give multiple substrings too, as shown in the example edit in my quetsion ?

Comment: @DhruvPathak, I added another code, if it is not exactly what you want.

Comment: the code still prints incorrectly, the expected output is ['manhatan','manhattin'] where as your sample code prints ['manhatan', 'manhattn']

Answer (score 17):

Recently I've written an alignment library for Python: https://github.com/eseraygun/python-alignment

Using it, you can perform both global and local alignments with arbitrary scoring strategies on any pair of sequences. Actually, in your case, you need semi-local alignments as you don't care for the substrings of `query_string`. I've simulated semi-local algorithm using local alignment and some heuristics in the following code but it is easy to extend the library for a proper implementation.

Here is the example code in the README file modified for your case.

```
from alignment.sequence import Sequence, GAP_ELEMENT
from alignment.vocabulary import Vocabulary
from alignment.sequencealigner import SimpleScoring, LocalSequenceAligner

large_string = "thelargemanhatanproject is a great project in themanhattincity"
query_string = "manhattan"

# Create sequences to be aligned.
a = Sequence(large_string)
b = Sequence(query_string)

# Create a vocabulary and encode the sequences.
v = Vocabulary()
aEncoded = v.encodeSequence(a)
bEncoded = v.encodeSequence(b)

# Create a scoring and align the sequences using local aligner.
scoring = SimpleScoring(1, -1)
aligner = LocalSequenceAligner(scoring, -1, minScore=5)
score, encodeds = aligner.align(aEncoded, bEncoded, backtrace=True)

# Iterate over optimal alignments and print them.
for encoded in encodeds:
    alignment = v.decodeSequenceAlignment(encoded)

    # Simulate a semi-local alignment.
    if len(filter(lambda e: e != GAP_ELEMENT, alignment.second)) != len(b):
        continue
    if alignment.first[0] == GAP_ELEMENT or alignment.first[-1] == GAP_ELEMENT:
        continue
    if alignment.second[0] == GAP_ELEMENT or alignment.second[-1] == GAP_ELEMENT:
        continue

    print alignment
    print 'Alignment score:', alignment.score
    print 'Percent identity:', alignment.percentIdentity()
    print
```

The output for `minScore=5` is as follows.

```
m a n h a - t a n
m a n h a t t a n
Alignment score: 7
Percent identity: 88.8888888889

m a n h a t t - i
m a n h a t t a n
Alignment score: 5
Percent identity: 77.7777777778

m a n h a t t i n
m a n h a t t a n
Alignment score: 7
Percent identity: 88.8888888889
```

If you remove the `minScore` argument, you will get only the best scoring matches.

```
m a n h a - t a n
m a n h a t t a n
Alignment score: 7
Percent identity: 88.8888888889

m a n h a t t i n
m a n h a t t a n
Alignment score: 7
Percent identity: 88.8888888889
```

Note that all algorithms in the library have `O(n * m)` time complexity, `n` and `m` being the lengths of the sequences.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem, and I found that neither of the top two answers worked. Instead, I used the following algorithm to detect the minimally wrong fuzzy match:

```
def fuzzy_substring_search(cls, major: str, minor: str, errs: int = 4) -> Optional[regex.Match]:
    """Find the closest matching fuzzy substring.

    Args:
        major: the string to search in
        minor: the string to search with
        errs: the total number of errors

    Returns:
        Optional[regex.Match] object
    """
    errs_ = 0
    s = regex.search(f"({minor}){{e<={errs_}}}", major)
    while s is None and errs_ <= errs:
        errs_ += 1
        s = regex.search(f"({minor}){{e<={errs_}}}", major)
    return s
```

This has the benefit of returning exact matches if they exist, and escalating fuzziness as needed.

Comment: Please do see the update in my question, I could find a module that worked well

Comment: @DhruvPathak I see your solution, and I don't doubt it works for your use case.