# Get index of python fuzzywuzzy match

Tags: python, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

I'm using Python `fuzzywuzzy` to find matches in a list of sentences:

```
def getMatches(needle):
     return process.extract(needle, bookSentences, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio, limit=3)
```

I'm trying to print out the match plus the sentences around it:

```
for match in matches:
     matchIndex = bookSentences.index(match)
     sentenceIndices = range(matchIndex-2,matchIndex+2)
     for index in sentenceIndices:
         print bookSentences[index],
     print '\n\n'
```

Unfortunately, the script fails to find the match in the original list:

> ValueError: (u'Thus, in addition to the twin purposes mentioned above, this book is written for at least two groups: 1.', 59) is not in list

Is there a better way to find the index of the match in the original list? Can `fuzzywuzzy` some how give it to me? There doesn't seem to be anything in the [readme](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/master/README.rst) about it.

How can I get the index in the original list of a match returned by `fuzzywuzzy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel a bit dumb. `fuzzywuzzy` returns a tuple including the score, not just the match. The solution:

```
for match in matches:
     matchIndex = bookSentences.index(match[0])
     sentenceIndices = range(matchIndex-2,matchIndex+2)
     for index in sentenceIndices:
         print bookSentences[index],
     print '\n\n'
```

Comment: This only works for the `process.extract` method, and only because the match returned is guaranteed to be in the list. I'm using `fuzzywuzzy` to search for substrings in a long block of text, using `fuzz.partial_ratio` which only returns a score. I think I'm going to have to check out SequenceMatcher for my purposes.

Comment: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31433394/721305) seems like a good option.

Comment: This seems like it adds an additional unnecessary step, I wish that fuzzywuzzy process returned the tuple in the form of (index, text, score)