# Fuzzy match one string with the start of another in Java

Tags: java, regex, fuzzy-comparison, edit-distance

As shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19696082/2205969) question, Python regex has a neat and concise functionality to fuzzy match one string against the start of a second string (up to `x` character changes).

In the following code snippet, `x=1` (see `e<=1`). The first string is `amazing`, and the second string is `amagingfiller`.

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.match('(amazing){e<=1}', 'amagingfiller')
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='amaging', fuzzy_counts=(1, 0, 0)>
```

`amazing` matches `amaging` because `amaging` is 1 or fewer changes from `amazing`. `filler` is ignored entirely. This is what is expected.

**Question 1**: Is there any equivalent functionality in Java's regex library?

**Question 2**: If not, what's an alternative way to solve this?

Comment: Why are you calling it "fuzzy split" if you're not splitting anything? Don't you mean "fuzzy match"?

Comment: Updated to make it clearer.

Comment: For my use case I want to use `amazing` to split `amagingfiller` into `amaging` and `filler`, hence why I used the term split. Agree "match" makes more sense in the context of the question though.

Comment: Note that it's not just for strings of the same length. I'd also expect `amazing` to match `amazzing` in `amazzingfiller` (edit distance=1), for instance.

Comment: I don't know if there's another regex implementation that offers this functionality but you may consider checking [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of Levenshtein but was hoping there might be an oven ready solution for the problem :)

Comment: 3 years later I'm looking for java alternative to this regex library. @Ian did you find something?